# SoundCloud Public Stream 403 Forbidden

Tags: c++, stream, soundcloud, juce

Using JUCE, I've gotten as far as getting the redirect link, but this result link does not work in code!

Oddly enough, a copy/paste of this link into the browser shows that it indeed works, but in code, the results from Windows are giving me 403 Forbidden.

Here's an example link obtained that worked in the browser when initially given, but not in code: http://soundcloud.vo.llnwd.net/ddkX2UbGyx41.128.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1395669031&Signature=V%2bw8zFd36gQNOFMVE5Tnx9lIUjQ%3d&e=1395669031&h=b7434c017179ca0393ef9656c16853ad

Any insight would be appreciated as to why this would be!

Comment: The link doesn't work in my browser. Just checked - its a blank page.

Comment: Yeah, it's no doubt timed-out at this point. When initially generated, it works fine in the browser.